# Gson JsonArray to List long type becomes scientific notation

Tags: java, gson

When I try to convert JsonArray to List, I get a long type conversion error, the code is as follows

```java
public static <T> ArrayList toArrayList(JsonArray jsonArray) {
    System.out.println("---=Receive====>>"+jsonArray);
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.setLongSerializationPolicy(LongSerializationPolicy.STRING).create();
    return gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(),
                         new TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.getType());
}
```

result:

```
--=Receive====>>[{"serialNo":"1339497989051277312","createBy":"xxxx","createDate":1608196182000,"updateBy":"xxxx","updateDate":1615444156000}]
-=result--->>[{serialNo=1339497989051277312, createBy=xxxx, createDate=1.608196182E12, updateBy=xxxx, updateDate=1.615444156E12}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example as your post is incomplete: 1) what is the actual JSON array object or the document it is constructed from? 2) what is your actual class of elements of the list you're trying to convert to?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the JSON as a standalone section but just noticed it right in the "receive" debug output. Anyway, the more clear your post is, the better it gets to whoever reads it and probably help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple issues with your code:

- The result list type is raw hence it's not type-safe at compile time.
- Prefer interfaces, `List`, rather than classes, `ArrayList`, if possible.
- The type parameter of `T` is not bound to the list it returns thus makes little sense if any.
- The way you're creating type token out of the type parameter does not work: at runtime it is still mapped to `java.lang.Object` and Gson trying to pick the
  best one it thinks of.
- Type tokens should not (and moreover cannot) be created in such methods but passed from the call site. Also, they are immutable hence thread-safe either.
- You don't need to create `Gson` instances every time you invoke this method.
- Converting JSON tree to a string for this case is very useless as Gson can traverse JSON trees and read JSON token streams not spending double time for
  parsing.

When I was asking you to provide the list element class, I tried to make a hint that your actual code like this:

```java
ArrayList arrayList = toArrayList(jsonArray);
System.out.println(arrayList);
```

cannot work. Note the following:

- This code (and probably yours either) does not do any mention on the element type at all.
- If you'd inspect the *real* list element class, you'd see that it is deserialized as `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap`--a generic type from Gson
  perspective I was talking above (`arrayList.get(0).getClass()`).
- JSON does not distinguish between "long", "integer", "short", "u64", "i8" and whatever like that. JSON numeric type is merely a *number*. Gson
  picks `java.lang.Double` as this type can cover most practical needs (`BigDecimal` would be a much better choice but it is also memory-consuming; this is also
  a why the `setLongSerializationPolicy` hint is ignored).

Gson did the best it could do for you and it did it.

What you have to do, summarizing it all up, is:

```java
private static final Gson gson=new GsonBuilder()
        .disableInnerClassSerialization()
        .disableHtmlEscaping()
        .create();

public static<E> List<E> toArrayList(final JsonArray jsonArray,final TypeToken<?extends List<? extends E>> typeToken){
        return gson.fromJson(jsonArray,typeToken.getType());
}
```

```java
final class MyObject {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("serialNo")
    final String serialNo;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("createBy")
    final String createBy;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("createDate")
    final long createDate;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("updateBy")
    final String updateBy;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("updateDate")
    final long updateDate;

    private MyObject(final String serialNo, final String createBy, final long createDate, final String updateBy, final long updateDate) {
        this.serialNo = serialNo;
        this.createBy = createBy;
        this.createDate = createDate;
        this.updateBy = updateBy;
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
    }

}
```

```java
private static final TypeToken<List<MyObject>> listOfMyObjectTypeToken = new TypeToken<List<MyObject>>() {};
// ...
final List<MyObject> myObjects = toArrayList(jsonArray, listOfMyObjectTypeToken);
System.out.println(myObjects);
System.out.println(myObjects.get(0).getClass().getSimpleName());
```

Passing the type token provides *enough* information to Gson what type to deal with. Here is why:

```
[MyObject(serialNo=1339497989051277312, createBy=xxxx, createDate=1608196182000, updateBy=xxxx, updateDate=1615444156000)]
MyObject
```

Comment: I have no way to create objects for conversion, because the elements in my JsonArray are indeterminate, all I need is to convert the JsonArray into a List to facilitate traversal operations.

Comment: Why do you even convert the JSON array then if `JsonArray` (and all `JsonElement` subclasses) can represent indeterminate JSON structures?